# Cannot POST / With Post request from non '/' site

Tags: html, node.js, http, web, post

I am new to Node and am having trouble with the POST functionality.
I have a simple website, where I have the following lines:

```
app.get('/sign',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'index.html'));
});

app.post('/sign', (req,res)=>{
    res.send("Success!")
});
```

The get request works perfectly fine, but when I post the data in the form back, instead of getting a success message, I get `Cannot POST /`.
When doing the same from the '/' directory with `app.get('/', etc.)`
it works fine.

This is the content of the 'index.html' file:

```
<form action = '/' method='POST' id="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="emal">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you share the code you’re using to “*post the data in the form back*”? It doesn’t appear that you’re POSTing to the correct endpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `action` attribute specifies the URL the form data will be posted to.

You have said to post it to `/`.

Your server side code provides a route for `/sign` but not `/`.

You need your URLs to match. Either change `action="/"` to `action="/sign"` to be explicit about where you are posting it to *or* remove the `action` attribute entirely so it posts to the *current url* (which is `/sign` since that is the route of the GET handler that provided the HTML document containing the form).